# System hangs when GPU is working

Tags: windows, ubuntu, drivers, graphics-card, gpu

I have this setup:

```
CPU AMD Ryzen 9 7950X 16 Core
GIGABYTE X670E AORUS MASTER
DDR5 Corsair VENGEANCE 5200 MHz 32 GB
AMD RADEON™ RX 6800 XT da 16 GB 
CORSAIR 850W RMx SERIES™
```

With a dual boot for Ubuntu 22.10 and Windows 11 Pro.
In both systems I installed the latest official AMD drivers (Ubuntu 22.40.3, Windows 23.4.1).

Using the [Superposition](https://benchmark.unigine.com/) Unigine benchmark tool I get the following results:

- in Ubuntu the test is completed (it does not matter, but with a score of 10192 for 1080P Extreme). It runs with opengl
- in Windows, with the same parameters it fails running either opengl or directx

"Fail" means that after 1-2 minutes the system hangs forever or even the screen goes black. I can only reset the machine.

I checked the temperatures and they are in range: CPU < 60 °C, GPU junction < 95 °C, GPU board < 67 °C.

I did a RAM test and checked the power supply size: I have a 850 W, while the required power is about 600W (according to the Coolermaster Power Supply calculator [tool](https://www.coolermaster.com/power-supply-calculator/)).

I also tried to install older drivers in Windows but the behavior is always the same.
Using the stress test feature of the driver itself or even running a game leads to hang the system. I checked that VBS is disabled in Windows.

Since in Ubuntu I was not able to reproduce the issue, my wild guess is it isn't a strictly hardware problem (even after such a hang, it takes about 20~30 seconds after reset to reach the BIOS screen).

Is there a rational and technical method to locate the problem instead of going at random?